# Is it possible to convert a small piece of VB.NET code to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to change a few lines of vb.net code to c# code as the code is so old.will it possible to convert a few lines of code without disturbing the structure.

For example, in this code

```
Restart:
        sIssCo = ""
        On Error GoTo ErrorRtn
        sErrorMsg = "Unable to activate Word."
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        oWord.Visible = True
        oWord.StatusBar = "Initiating Word Merge..."
        oWord.System.Cursor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorWait
        oWord.StatusBar = "Deleting previous temp docs..."
        On Error GoTo ErrorRtn
        If Dir(gsTempFileDir & "*.doc") <> "" Then
        oFileSys.DeleteFile(gsTempFileDir & "*.doc")
        End If
```

I just want to change the below lines to c#

```
If Dir(gsTempFileDir & "*.doc") <> "" Then
    oFileSys.DeleteFile(gsTempFileDir & "*.doc")
End If
```

I have tried the below piece of code.

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(gsTempFileDir.FullName, "*.doc").Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in gsTempFileDir.GetFiles("*.doc"))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

It is not supporting as the code is in vb.net, I have also added few assemblies like Imports

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports System.IO.Directory
Imports System.IO.File
```

to make it compatible for c# code, it was not working either. Any other possible way like `System.IO.oFileSys.delete(gsTempFileDir & "*.doc")` like this?

Comment: In a VB.NET project you can only have VB.NET code. You can create a C# project, put your C# code there and reference that project from your VB project and call the needed functions.

Comment: I highly recommend to use the .NET framework classes whenever possible in VB and avoid methods from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace like the ```Dir()``` method. This is IMHO beneficial in two ways: a) it helps you to get familiar with the .NET framework and b) it's much easier to translate back and forth between VB.NET <-> C#.

Comment: There's no reason to write C# code. You can write VB but use the same types and members that you did in the C#. You don't have to write VB.NET code as though it was VB6 and you absolutely shouldn't. That VB code should not have been written like that in the first place, but was probably either copied directly from VB6 or was written by someone who knew VB6 but didn't know VB.NET properly.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to write C# code at all? Just write VB.NET code but write it properly, rather than as though it was VB6. This:

```cs
if (Directory.GetFiles(gsTempFileDir.FullName, "*.doc").Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in gsTempFileDir.GetFiles("*.doc"))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

can be written almost exactly the same in VB:

```vb
If Directory.GetFiles(gsTempFileDir.FullName, "*.doc").Length > 0 Then
    For Each file In gsTempFileDir.GetFiles("*.doc")
        file.Delete()
    Next
End If
```

Of course, that's got it's own issues but that's what you wrote. If you want to do it properly though, why call `GetFiles` twice? Just call it once and loop over the results. If the resulting array is empty then the loop will do nothing. No need for an `If` statement. You can call `Directory.GetFiles`:

```vb
For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles(gsTempFileDir.FullName, "*.doc")
    File.Delete(filePath)
Next
```

or `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`:

```vb
For Each file In gsTempFileDir.GetFiles("*.doc")
    file.Delete()
Next
```